# How can I determine if I have one process with two threads, or two processes?

Tags: windows, process, task-manager

I notice that chrome (famously now), creates loads of instances in task manager. Is that lots of threads and one process? Or is it multiple processes.  i.e. is task manager showing threads, or is it showing processes?

Suppose I go to the orb/start, and I launch cmd, then I go there again and launch another cmd. Is that two separate processes, rather than one process with two threads?

Now suppose I launch a cmd, then from there, I launch another cmd. Is that one process two threads? Or is that two processes?

Comment: that are processes http://superuser.com/a/1065847/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981  looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190949/create-multiple-threads-and-wait-all-of-them-to-complete i'd guess that it's the case that a thread always involves specific functions within the said process, and never involves invoking a process?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Mark explained it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows "Task Manager" *only* shows processes. (Otherwise you would see *a lot* of duplicates for everything, since almost all Windows apps are multi-threaded, including Chrome.) To see threads of a process, use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) or [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/); both of them have a "Threads" tab in the process properties dialog.

[image]

When you run something via *Run…* or Command Prompt, it *always* starts as a new process. It doesn't make any sense for it to be a new thread in an existing process, since threads share memory and other resources, so a new thread created "from nowhere" just wouldn't know what to do with what it got; it'd trample all over the running app.

- That said, once the new process starts, it can *contact* an existing instance. That's what both Chrome and Firefox do – they just send a "hey, the user wants a new window" IPC message to the 'master' Firefox process, and exit immediately afterwards.
- As for that new window, usually it *doesn't* get a new thread on its own – most of the time, if a single process decides to open multiple windows, they all run on the same "UI thread", since only the main thread receives [window messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381405(v=vs.85).aspx). Instead, additional threads are used for background and/or long-running tasks.

---

As a side note, the Linux [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/htop-2.0.png) tool *does* show all threads by default (since Linux threads are no different from processes), and this confuses people every single time. If you use htop, make sure to select either "Show custom thread names" (as in the linked screenshot) or "Hide userland threads" (to get a traditional processes-only list).

For example, here's a small part of Linux Chromium's process tree, including both subprocesses and their threads (the main process didn't fit in the screenshot):

[image]

<sub>(Note that despite their green colouring, threads shown in htop *are not* [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).)</sub>