# How to setup or where to find a single-threaded browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, threads

For test purpose I want to limit Firefox or any other browser to one to maximally ten threads, but can't find any docu guiding this.

Alternative solution I guess would be an old single-threaded FF version. Don't know exactly, but [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/luke/2012/01/24/jsruntime-is-now-officially-single-threaded/) seems to be something related to what I'm looking for.

Any advice with a browser version or setting would help.

Comment: unless firefox comes with a hidden configuration setting that does exactly what you want, your only option is to configure the OS to execute the program the way you want. it is likely (I;ve seen lots of questions about controlling an apps threading externally over the years) that you won't be able to accomplish what you want. Apps use threads at their (and only their) discretion, regardless of how many cores they have available. even if you had a single core CPU, the code would still execute many threads and let the OS schedule them as appropriate. what precisely do you want to do?

Comment: @FrankThomas I want to test a service quality of a proxy provider, who gives a test access limited to ten threads. I tried just to change browser's settings to use proxy gateway - but failed. The answer of proxy provider was: "browser uses much more then 10 threads. Thats why you can't get connection".

Comment: In that case, they are not talking about actual system threads, they are talking about concurrent TCP connections. When I loaded this webpage, my browser loaded files from 25 different URLs (hit F12 and look at the network tab to see all the files that this page is made of). each of those downloads represented one thread, but we're only worried about the maximum Concurrent requests at any given millisecond, not the total number of requests, and certianly not the total number of CPU threads. a proxy would not know or care about threads that didn't generate a network request.

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing the Firefox performance settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/performance-settings):
[image: Firefox Performance Settings]

1. Open the *Options* (or *Preferences*) settings to the *General* section.
2. Un-check *Use recommended performance settings*.
3. Set *Content process limit* to 1.

N.B. I've not tested this; it might be that Firefox would still initiate more than one thread.

Comment: I thought to do so, but then i've got doubts: is it really the same: process and thread?

Comment: Open gnome-system-monitor or Task Manager and see how many processes are used. Try opening additional tabs in Firefox and check again. What do you see?

Comment: I thought process is about CPU, while thread is about network... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Evgeniy, no neither of those is correct. please see here to start: https://superuser.com/questions/1065826/handles-vs-threads-vs-processes/1065847 . Threads are about CPU, and processes are about Memory/OS. One common use of muti-threaded applications is IO (network or otherwise), and when used correctly, can allow the computer to work on meaningful tasks while its waiting on other tasks (like downloading a file) to complete.  Note that this firefox setting is about Processes, not threads. All processes will contain at least one unique thread at all times, but can have many at any time.

Comment: cont. The modern firefox configuration will run one process per tab. The reason for this is that all threads in a process have access to all the memory in that process, so Firefox choose to split tabs up into different processes so that bad sites executing javascript in one tab can't access privledged data held by another tab.